# What's the association between vc100 (default generator for Visual Studio 2010) and C++11/C++14?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm a new hand in C++ and I've got a question about some Visual Studio version names.

C++98, C++11 and C++14 are versions of the ISO/IEC 14882 standard for the C++ programming language; this means, for example, C++11 has some new features added or modified compared to C++98, C++14 has some new features added or modified compared to C++11, like the upgrade.

When I'm using Visual Studio as the IDE to develop programs, I also noticed another thing called "vc100" (for Visual Studio 2010), "vc140" (for Visual Studio 2019)... it's called generator. I supposed that's also called the version of compiler, like the version of GCC.

So, the confusion is, what's the association between C++11 and the generator name (like "vc100"); or, to be specific, does the year part in the generator called "Visual Studio 2010" (2010 is the year here) means it doesn't support C++11 and later, but only supports C++98?

Comment: Different versions of vs support different versions of the standard. 2010 wouldn't, for example, support c++14, 17, or 20.

Comment: Does support bits of c++11, though. [This chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170) used to cover VS 2010, but I guess that's far enough in the rearview that they lost it around a corner.

Comment: Great! I do find vc100 supports bits of c++11! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct connection or association between the names of the various versions of the Visual C/C++ compiler and any particular C++ Standard. Nor is there actually a direct correlation between the name of the compiler (e.g. vc100) and the 'year' part of the name of the corresponding version of Visual Studio.

In the case of VS-2010, there is an *incidental* overlap between the year and the version number (10.0); but, as can be seen from the [Visual Studio Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info), that year/version is the only one where the numbers coincide.

Note also that a compiler released in 2010 (as was vc100) is extremely unlikely to *fully* support the C++11 Standard (though VS and MSVC often have provisional support for the 'next' due Standard, if a working draft is available); however, later versions of MSVC generally have 'retro' support for several earlier Standards: The latest version (VS-2022) has the option of using C++14, C++17, C++20 or (experimentally) the provisional C++23 Standard. When compiling code with Visual Studio, you can select/specify which of the C++ Standards you want to follow in each project's settings.

Comment: I noticed that vc100 does support some of the features in C++ and later. (Updated vc100 I supposed, not the old one released in year 2010). The information is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: The wrinkle is that a 2010-dated implementation may support some features in draft standards that were later ratified in C++11.    Certainly, historically, compilers (and vendors including Microsoft) have supported features before their later ratification in the standard.   Microsoft has also (like other vendors) influenced evolution of the standard, so sometimes they have implemented some feature and then lobbied for its introduction into the standard (sometimes ratification occurred "as is", sometimes it was rejected, sometimes the proposal was tweaked before adoption).

Comment: @Peter Yeah. I could mention that - it's sort of implied by my later statement about VS-2022 supporting a provisional C++23 but maybe I should make it clearer in the post.

Comment: Nice! Learned a lot!